# How to efficiently determine the depth of closures

Tags: javascript, closures

In terms of closure, if only account for *functions that return another function* as shown in the following examples. How do we programmatically determine the **depth of this closure** in runtime?

Let's say this function `F` has the depth of 2:

```
function F(a){ // 1
    return function G(b){ // 2
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

This function 'H' has the depth of 3.

```
function H(a){ // 1
   return function(b){ //2
      return function(c){} //3
   }
}
```

So far I have made some simple script to determine the depth of closure by iteratively checks the return type of a function until it returns other type than the function. **But my script only works in the case where each nested function requires no argument**. See the following code:

```
function F(){
    return function(){
        return function(){
            return 1;
        }
   }
}

function depth(f){
    var n = 1;
    var ret = f();
    while (typeof(ret)=='function'){
        ret = ret(); 
        n++;
    }
    return n; 
}
```

The simple function `depth` above correctly determines the depth of `F` which is 3. **However, in some real-world cases such as closures which take function as argument and invoke it, my function `depth` cannot deal with.**

```
function F2(a,f){
    return function(g){
        return f(a) + g(a); // This will break my depth function
   }
}
```

***My question** : *Is there any way to determine how deep my closure is more efficiently?* Especially in some cases mentioned above (closures which take function as argument and invoke it). Generic way which can dynamically cope with closures which may or may not take some functions as arguments will be most appreciated.

***P.S.*** Let me narrow down the scopes as follows.

- Only pure nested functions are taken into account.
- Each layer of nested function always returns the same type.
- The depth of the function is constant.
- Neither one of the nested functions is recursive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80193/discussion-on-question-by-tao-p-r-how-to-efficiently-determine-the-depth-of-cl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach. This works at runtime by observing how the code behaves. 

My function `Reflector` is the special sauce in this case.

See https://jsfiddle.net/rffv34oz/8/ for running the example.

The function `Reflector` does four things:

1. It "instruments" a function with a hook (`fh`) by returning the hook instead of the original function. The effect is that the hook is called before that instrumented function is called.

2. When the instrumented function is called, it forwards the call - it calls the original function. And remains ready for capturing the function result.

3. When the function returns, it inspects the result. If the result is also a function, it stores new maximum depth.

4. Also, when the returned result was a function, the hook also instruments the returned function, so that step (1) is again applied for the new returned function.

```
//Your function You want to USE and REFLECT on too.
function F(){ 
    //return 3;
    return function(){
        //return 2;
        return function(){
            return 1;
        }
   }
}

//Your function You want to USE and REFLECT on too.
function H(a){ // 1
    return function(b){ //2
        return function(c){ //3
            return a + b + c;   
        }
   }    
}

//this function is the machinery that knows how to USE the functions You want to measure. 
//But this function only USES them, but does no reflection.
function BlackboxF(f) { 

    var r1 = f();
    if (typeof r1 == "function")
    {
        var r2 = r1();
        if (typeof r2 == "function")
        {
            var r3 = r2();  

            return r3;
        }
        else 
        {
            return r2;   
        }
    }
    else 
    {
         return r1;   
    }

}

//this function is the machinery that knows how to USE the functions You want to measure. 
//But this function only USES them, but does no reflection.
function BlackboxH(f) { 

    var r1 = f(1);
    var r2 = r1(2);
    var r3 = r2(4);
    return r3;

}

var maxdepth = 1;

//This is the special agent for reflecting code as it runs
function Reflector(f, depth) { 

    if (!depth)
        depth = 1;

    //1. It "instruments" a function with a hook (`fh`) by returning the hook 
    //instead of the original function. The effect is that the hook is called 
    //before that instrumented function is called.
    var fh = function()     
    {
        //2. When the instrumented function is called, it forwards the call - it calls 
        //the original function. And remains ready for capturing the function result.
        var r = f.apply(this, arguments);    

        //3. When the function returns, it inspects the result. 
        //If the result is also a function, it stores new maximum depth.
        if (typeof r == "function")
        {
            maxdepth = Math.max(maxdepth, depth + 1);

            //4. Also, when the returned result was a function, the hook also 
            //instruments the returned function, so that step (1) is again applied 
            //for the new returned function.
            return Reflector(r, depth + 1);        
        }
        else 
        {
            return r;
        }
    };

    return fh;
}

if (false) //The simple case with no arguments
{
    var F2 = Reflector(F);
    var RF = BlackboxF(F2);

    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Result: " + RF;
    document.getElementById("depth").textContent = "Depth: " + maxdepth;
}
else //A more complicated case with arguments
{
    var H2 = Reflector(H);
    var RH = BlackboxH(H2);

    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Result: " + RH;
    document.getElementById("depth").textContent = "Depth: " + maxdepth;
}
```

Comment: Your reflector approach looks interesting to me. However, it looks a bit more complicated than I anticipated. Can you please explain how did you design it?

Comment: @TaoP.R. I added explanations about the workings of `Reflector` in my answer text and inserted the explanation also into the code. Is it more clear now or You want to clarify something more? Also, if You want, this approach can be upgraded even more so that it is able to reflect on multiple "root" functions (`F` and `H`) concurrently and report the depth for each separately. I did not add such code right now, since the answer would get too long this way. But if necessary, I can add general explanations about the approach one needs to take to observe multiple "root" functions concurrently.

Comment: So the most important factor would be "we need to know how to pass appropriate arguments to each function". This reflector seems to work well in general cases.

Comment: @TaoP.R. If You are willing to predefine the argument types to something basic (for example, numerics), and You allow using some base value for all these arguments (for example, zero), then there is a trick to bypass the need for the machinery that knows how to use the functions, and generate the calls automatically. Actually, the need for basic types is not strict - just likely, but the need for allowing the use of some common base value is necessary.

Comment: I think your approach potentially gives me some ideas. I'll try to extend and customize it further to make it more flexible. All I need is a general way which we don't need to know how to call beforehand, but your approach can be extended to deal with it (I foresee). So I accept this.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but it's better to format here.

This is not a solvable problem unless you give a set of all required parameters.
Consider calculating the *"depth"* of the following:

```
function F(a) {
    if (a) {
        return function G(b) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has excluded such cases from his question only 10m ago :-)

Comment: @Bergi Not everyone is reading the updated version of the question, but thanks for the note.

Comment: This case makes things much more complicated as discussed in the replies to the question. So I decided to opt out this case.

Comment: An update to `else { return function H(b) { return function J(c) {return 1;}}` is quite possibly not excluded, depending, of course, on the OP's precise defintion of "the same type".

Comment: @ScottSauyet Hmm, that's a bit tricky case. However variable depth could be too difficult to solve with general ways.

Comment: I have updated the scope accordingly. Let's ignore variable depth then. This is way too complicated for finding general ways.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe are able to change all the functions so that they are capable of running without arguments too, for Your reflection purpose? 

Since during the depth calculation the function calls should not do any other useful computation or have any side effects anyway. They should just return a function or a non-function value. 

Since You say: "Each layer of nested function always returns the same type.
The depth of the function is constant." the decision to return a dummy response of corresponding type upon encountering empty argument list should be simple one.

Comment: Do you mean changing each layer of the functions by removing its function body? I'm not quite sure how to actually implement this, perhaps by monkey-patching? Kinda no idea on how to programmatically alter the function without making any changes to their (nested) return values.

Comment: @TaoP.R. Here I meant that You add a couple of lines to the function header code, not removing its body or changing its *defined* functionality at all. If You want programmatic solution then see my second answer.